# Respond via websockets to a HTTP request, in Flask-Sockets

Tags: flask, websocket

I have a client which is going to make a call:

```
/startLongCalculation/12345
```

via HTTP, and the server will return a jobid.

They already have a websockets connection open to the Flask-Sockets server.

At some point in the future (several seconds or even minutes later), the calculation will finish. I'd like to send an event containing that jobid back along the websockets connection, but I can't figure out how to get the context I need.

Comment: I'm not married to Flask. A simple example of how to do this in, say, Twisted would be fine too.

Comment: Or, am I just "doing this wrong", and should I absolutely just send the original call over the websockets pipe?

Comment: Can you show some code, where the socket connection is handled? You don't need any context, but you probably have to incorporate some way to pass an event (or something with the same use) to the piece of code, that handles the websocket.

Comment: I spoke to the author, and it turns out this is not possible :/

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188874/why-is-gevent-websocket-synchronous) can help you? Instead of `gevent.sleep` pull from a queue like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). (I've never used celery personally, so maybe that will not work too)

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing (I'm looking at apscheduler right now).

Comment: Does it work as expected? Or does your problem still persist?

Comment: could use redis pub/sub too

Comment: I've ended up not using websockets at all, and just having the client send a HTTP request, get a job id, and then poll periodically (every 10 seconds or so) with that job id asking for status. The application is so low-volume (users in the single digits simultaneous) that I don't have to worry about performance.