# Websocket : page that constantly receives data through websocket from server cannot be multiple times

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, bottle, web-frameworks

server.py uses bottle as a webframework and bottle_websocket
    to senad data with 1 sec period to the frontend which is html page
    that updates and creates real time graph as data arrives in
    javascript code. I have three scenarious:

1. When the page is idle I mean when data is not sent from the server
   through websocket I can open multiple tabs on my browser.
2. When
   there is only one client running on localhost:8001 address that
   receives data from websocket I cannot open another tab( I cannot
   other client fromt he beginning)
3. When there is already opened
   multiple tabs on the browser and when I start receiving data from
   only one client all clients are being updated.

my content of the server.py is as following

```
from bottle import get,template,run,route,Bottle,static_file
from bottle import get,template,run,route,Bottle,static_file
from bottle.ext.websocket import GeventWebSocketServer
from bottle.ext.websocket import websocket
import random
import time

users = set()
@get('/')
def mainIndex():
    return template('indexStackoverflow')

@get('/websocket', apply=[websocket])
def chat(ws):
     users.add(ws)
     i = 0
     while i < 20:
         msg = ws.receive()
         speed = random.randrange(0,1000)
         i = i + 1      
         if msg is not None:
              for u in users:
                   u.send(str(speed))        
         else:
            print "msg is NONe is guesse"
            break
         time.sleep(1)    
    for u in users:
        u.close()
    users.remove(ws)
    ws.close()

@route('/js/<filename:path>')
def static(filename):
    return static_file(filename,root='js/')

run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8001,server=GeventWebSocketServer)
```

and the content of the indexStackoverflow.html is

```js
        var margin = {top:5, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 70},
            width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var data1;
        var x,y1,xAxis1,yAxis1,update;
        var duration = 1000;
 var moveDuration = 1000;
        // Parse the date / time
                var totalSeconds = 60;
                var n = 10;//totalSeconds;
  var limit = n;
                duration = 800;
                x = d3.time.scale()
                           .domain([0, ((n - 1) * duration)])
                           .range([0, width]);
        var valueline1 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d,i) { return x(i*duration); })
                .y(function(d,i) { return y1(d); })
                .interpolate("monotone");

   // Set the ranges
                data1 = [0];
                

                y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
                                        .domain([0,1000]);
               xAxis1 =d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                                .orient("bottom")
                                .ticks(d3.time.seconds, 1.0)
                                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%M:%S'))
                                .innerTickSize(-height);
                yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
                        .innerTickSize(-width)
                        .outerTickSize(0)
                        .tickPadding(10)
                        .orient("left").ticks(10);
   var svg = d3.select("#graph1")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
               svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height); 
                
  var xAxisLine= svg.append("g")                     // Add the X Axis
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+width+"," + height + ")")
                        .call(xAxis1);
  
  svg.append("g")                     // Add the Y Axis
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .call(yAxis1)
   ;

                var path = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
                                .append("path")
                                .data(data1)
                                .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d",valueline1(data1))
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width )+")")
    ;          // Add the valueline path.
 var random = d3.random.normal(0, 50);
 var  i = 0;
 var shifter = 0;
       function update(val){
                var svg1 = d3.select("#graph1");
                i = i + 1;
                shifter = 0;
                var val = JSON.parse(val);
                data1.push(val); 

                if(i >= limit){
                        shifter = x(-duration);
                        svg.select(".line")
    .attr("d", valueline1(data1))
    .attr("transform","")
    .transition()
                                .duration(moveDuration)
                                .ease("linear")
                                .attr("transform","translate("+(shifter)+")")
                                ;

                        var x_axis_scale = d3.time.scale()
                                                .domain([(i+1-limit)*duration,((n-1+(i+1-limit))*duration)])
                                                .range([0,width]);
                        svg.select(".x.axis")
    .attr("transition",null)
                                .transition()
                                .duration(moveDuration)
                                .ease("linear")
     .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x_axis_scale)
     .orient("bottom")
                                 .ticks(d3.time.seconds, 1.0)
                                 .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%M:%S'))
                                 .innerTickSize(-height)
    );
                        data1.shift();
                }
                else{
                        shifter = width - x(i*duration);
                        svg.select(".x.axis")
                               .transition()
                                .duration(moveDuration)
                               .ease("linear")
                                .attr("transform","translate("+(shifter)+","+(height)+")");
                        
   svg.select(".line")   // change the line
                                .attr("d", valueline1(data1))
                                .transition()
                                .duration(moveDuration)
                                .ease("linear")
                                .attr("transform","translate("+(shifter)+")")
                                ;
                        }
        }
var  ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/websocket')
ws.onopen = function(evt) {
}

ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
 //alert(evt.data)       
 update(evt.data);
 ws.send("arrived");
}
$('#startBtn').submit(function() {
 ws.send("Pressed");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
    <form id="startBtn">
            <input type="submit" value="Start Real" />
    </form>
<div id = "graph1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/websocketStackoverflow.js"></script>
```

and the websocketStackoverflow.js is locatedat js folder. To run the server first run on the terminal python server.py

I will be very glad for your any guidance/tips to overcome this problem.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188874/why-is-gevent-websocket-synchronous

Comment: Also: you're not monkey patching (gevent); not sure whether you need to here, but you may want to check.